# can't get the data in app.component Ionic / Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, side-menu

I try to make a mobile application using Ionic with angular: and this application has a login page that the employee will enter his information and after he login, I will get that information to show it in the side menu in the next page but the problem is I can't get this information because the side menu page is the app.component
that means the application will load the app.component first after that it will load the other pages
in my case, I will show information before I load it from the data base

Answer (score 0):

You can use Observbles for subscribe changes. I think is better to have `Subject<string>` and subscribe that. in login you can `Next` that, in this solution in all of your app, you can refresh data.